# query prints objects instead of some names in django

Tags: html, django, python-3.x, django-models

Is there a simple way to remove query set objects in my template just to print product name without the objects 
 what it prints 
[image]

```
  class SellerAccountMixin(object):
        products = []

        def get_products(self):
            account = self.get_account()
            products = Product.objects.filter(seller=account)
            self.products = products
            return products

class SellerDashboard(SellerAccountMixin,FormMixin, View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context["products"] = self.get_products()
        return render(request, "sellers/dashboard.html", context)
```

template

```
{% if products %}
   <div class='pull-left col-sidebar '>
    {{ products }}
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should *iterate* over your `products`, like:

```
{% if products %}
  <div class='pull-left col-sidebar '>
    {% for product in products %}{{ product.name }} {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

`.name` might be a different field. It should be the one you aim to render.